# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'firebase/app' in Kotlin/JS

Tags: firebase, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-js

In a Kotlin/JS project, I have added the Firebase dependency -

```
implementation(npm("firebase", "9.14.0"))
```

Added the external declaration file:

```
@file:JsModule("firebase/app")
@file:JsNonModule
@file:Suppress(
    "INTERFACE_WITH_SUPERCLASS",
    "OVERRIDING_FINAL_MEMBER",
    "RETURN_TYPE_MISMATCH_ON_OVERRIDE",
    "CONFLICTING_OVERLOADS"
)
package externals

import kotlin.js.Promise

external fun deleteApp(app: FirebaseApp): Promise<Unit>

external interface FirebaseApp {
    var name: String
    var options: FirebaseOptions
    var automaticDataCollectionEnabled: Boolean
}

external interface FirebaseAppSettings {
    var name: String?
        get() = definedExternally
        set(value) = definedExternally
    var automaticDataCollectionEnabled: Boolean?
        get() = definedExternally
        set(value) = definedExternally
    var setting: String
}

external interface FirebaseOptions {
    var apiKey: String?
        get() = definedExternally
        set(value) = definedExternally
    var authDomain: String?
        get() = definedExternally
        set(value) = definedExternally
    var databaseURL: String?
        get() = definedExternally
        set(value) = definedExternally
    var projectId: String?
        get() = definedExternally
        set(value) = definedExternally
    var storageBucket: String?
        get() = definedExternally
        set(value) = definedExternally
    var messagingSenderId: String?
        get() = definedExternally
        set(value) = definedExternally
    var appId: String?
        get() = definedExternally
        set(value) = definedExternally
    var measurementId: String?
        get() = definedExternally
        set(value) = definedExternally
}

external fun getApp(name: String = definedExternally): FirebaseApp

external fun getApps(): Array<FirebaseApp>

external fun initializeApp(options: FirebaseOptions, name: String = definedExternally): FirebaseApp

external fun initializeApp(options: FirebaseOptions): FirebaseApp

external fun initializeApp(options: FirebaseOptions, config: FirebaseAppSettings = definedExternally): FirebaseApp

external fun initializeApp(): FirebaseApp

external fun registerVersion(libraryKeyOrName: String, version: String, variant: String = definedExternally)

external val SDK_VERSION: String

external fun setLogLevel(logLevel: String /* "debug" | "verbose" | "info" | "warn" | "error" | "silent" */)
```

Next I have called the `initializeApp` function to initialize the firebase.

```
val options: dynamic = object {}
val config: dynamic = object {}
options["appId"] = "xxx"
options["apiKey"] = "xxx"
initializeApp(options.unsafeCast<FirebaseOptions>())
```

After that I am getting this error - **Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'firebase/app'**

Need help regarding this and Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved after degrading the version of Firebase NPM library to `9.13.0`

```
implementation(npm("firebase", "9.13.0"))
```